# How to migrate MikTeX to TeXLive/MacTeX

Tags: packages, miktex, texlive, installing, mactex

I was pretty comfortable in using ProTeXt distro of MikTeX (2013) in my Windows-7 netbook. When I switched over to a MacBook, I installed MacTeX, Mac variant of TeXLive (2014).

In spite of its huge size, I feel that many of the packages available in the ProTeXt-MikTeX distro is not present in MacTeX-TeXLive distro.

Of course, I could install them one by one. But I would like a more efficient way to do this.

Is there any way I could somehow list all the packages installed in MikTeX and install/migrate those in MacTeX-TeXLive in a single step or two? Anything simpler than the trivial one-by-one method will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which are these packages you are missing? Usually it is the contrary: MikTeX has to use its package installer to download and install packages that are already there in TeX Live.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: A few things are missing from TeX Live that are in MiKTeX due to licensing considerations. Beyond that, the coverage is very similar.

Comment: Most of those packages just mentioned by @JosephWright are relics from old times, LaTeX2.09 packages rusting and dusting in some template found in the outer skirts of the internet. Sure you really need them?

Comment: Some of the missing packages include stfloats.sty, thesis.cls (I know there are may other thesis alternatives present in TeXLive, but I need this one), the set of publication classes like IEEETrans, svjour, etc.